# App freezing in ion-input lost focus event - ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m facing a problem after to update my MacOS to Mojave version, I don’t know why but now, after to build my project to IOS (It happens only in IOS), I have a problem with a ion-input, that I use to enter a money value, always after to lost the focus my App freezes, Do you Know what can I do to fix it?

I’m using this method to apply a mask in ion-input:
https://marlosirapuan.com/maskmoney-no-ionic-2/

tried to remove this method but I still have the same problem…

When I build the same project in a Android device everything is working fine.

This is my environment

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Dede:getapp dede$ ionic info
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.19.3
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.1
global packages:
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
local packages:
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.12
Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.1 ios 4.5.5
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.5.0
System:
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy : 1.9.4
Node : v8.12.0
npm : 6.4.1
OS : macOS
Xcode : Xcode 10.0 Build version 10A255
Environment Variables:
ANDROID_HOME : /Users/dede/Library/Android/sdk/
Misc:
backend : pro

MY PACKAGE.JSON:
{
“name”: “aplicativo”,
“version”: “0.0.1”,
“author”: “Ionic Framework”,
“homepage”: “http://ionicframework.com/”,
“private”: true,
“scripts”: {
“clean”: “ionic-app-scripts clean”,
“build”: “ionic-app-scripts build”,
“lint”: “ionic-app-scripts lint”,
“ionic:build”: “ionic-app-scripts build”,
“ionic:serve”: “ionic-app-scripts serve”
},
“dependencies”: {
“@angular/common”: “4.1.3”,
“@angular/compiler”: “4.1.3”,
“@angular/compiler-cli”: “4.1.3”,
“@angular/core”: “4.1.3”,
“@angular/forms”: “4.1.3”,
“@angular/http”: “4.1.3”,
“@angular/platform-browser”: “4.1.3”,
“@angular/platform-browser-dynamic”: “4.1.3”,
“@ionic-native/barcode-scanner”: “^3.14.0”,
“@ionic-native/camera”: “^3.14.0”,
“@ionic-native/core”: “3.12.1”,
“@ionic-native/device”: “^3.14.0”,
“@ionic-native/diagnostic”: “^3.14.0”,
“@ionic-native/file”: “^3.14.0”,
“@ionic-native/geolocation”: “^3.14.0”,
“@ionic-native/in-app-browser”: “^3.14.0”,
“@ionic-native/native-audio”: “^4.0.1”,
“@ionic-native/native-storage”: “^3.14.0”,
“@ionic-native/push”: “^3.14.0”,
“@ionic-native/splash-screen”: “3.12.1”,
“@ionic-native/status-bar”: “3.12.1”,
“@ionic-native/vibration”: “^3.14.0”,
“@ionic/storage”: “^2.0.0”,
“@types/jquery”: “^3.2.17”,
“build”: “^0.1.4”,
“cordova-android”: “7.1.1”,
“cordova-android-support-gradle-release”: “^1.4.5”,
“cordova-browser”: “^4.1.0”,
“cordova-ios”: “4.5.5”,
“cordova-plugin-add-swift-support”: “^1.7.1”,
“cordova-plugin-camera”: “^4.0.3”,
“cordova-plugin-console”: “^1.1.0”,
“cordova-plugin-device”: “^2.0.2”,
“cordova-plugin-file”: “^6.0.1”,
“cordova-plugin-file-transfer”: “^1.7.1”,
“cordova-plugin-geolocation”: “^4.0.1”,
“cordova-plugin-inappbrowser”: “^3.0.0”,
“cordova-plugin-ionic-webview”: “^1.2.1”,
“cordova-plugin-nativeaudio”: “^3.0.9”,
“cordova-plugin-nativestorage”: “^2.3.2”,
“cordova-plugin-splashscreen”: “^4.1.0”,
“cordova-plugin-statusbar”: “^2.4.2”,
“cordova-plugin-vibration”: “^3.1.0”,
“cordova-plugin-whitelist”: “^1.3.3”,
“cordova-sqlite-storage”: “^2.5.0”,
“cordova-support-google-services”: “^1.1.0”,
“cordova.plugins.diagnostic”: “^4.0.10”,
“device”: “0.3.9”,
“io”: “1.0.0”,
“ionic-angular”: “3.5.0”,
“ionic-audio”: “^3.1.0”,
“ionic-plugin-keyboard”: “^2.2.1”,
“ionicons”: “3.0.0”,
“jquery”: “^3.2.1”,
“phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner”: “^8.0.0”,
“phonegap-plugin-multidex”: “^1.0.0”,
“phonegap-plugin-push”: “^2.2.3”,
“rxjs”: “5.4.0”,
“sw-toolbox”: “3.6.0”,
“tslint-config-airbnb”: “^5.2.1”,
“zone.js”: “0.8.12”
},
“devDependencies”: {
“@ionic/app-scripts”: “1.3.12”,
“@ionic/lab”: “1.0.6”,
“typescript”: “2.3.4”
},
“description”: “An Ionic project”,
“cordova”: {
“plugins”: {
“cordova-plugin-console”: {},
“cordova-plugin-splashscreen”: {},
“cordova-plugin-statusbar”: {},
“cordova-plugin-whitelist”: {},
“ionic-plugin-keyboard”: {},
“cordova-plugin-nativeaudio”: {},
“cordova-plugin-ionic-webview”: {},
“cordova-sqlite-storage”: {},
“cordova-android-support-gradle-release”: {
“ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION”: “27.+”
},
“phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner”: {
“ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION”: “27.+”
},
“cordova-plugin-nativestorage”: {},
“cordova-plugin-geolocation”: {
“GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION”: “To locate you”
},
“cordova.plugins.diagnostic”: {},
“cordova-plugin-camera”: {
“CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION”: " ",
“PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION”: " "
},
“cordova-plugin-file”: {},
“cordova-plugin-file-transfer”: {},
“cordova-plugin-inappbrowser”: {},
“cordova-plugin-vibration”: {},
“cordova-plugin-device”: {},
“phonegap-plugin-push”: {
“SENDER_ID”: “880917288043”,
“FCM_VERSION”: “11.6.2”,
“ANDROID_SUPPORT_V13_VERSION”: “27.+”
}
},
“platforms”: [
“browser”,
“android”,
“ios”
]
}
}
```

any suggestion? thanks my dear friends!